# devise email confirmation link leads to a dead end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find it. My devise sign up system was working fine yesterday; the emails were being sent, and clicking on the confirmation link in the email confirmed the account and redirected the user to the home page.

Today, the email still sends, but when I click on the confirmation link, I get the error message that "this webpage is not available," and the account isn't confirmed.

I recently switched from a vagrant virtual machine to nitrous.io, so this issue may have something to do with that . . . the url for my local version of my app isn't localhost:3000 anymore, and that's still what it says in the confirmation link. But the devise code doesn't specify localhost:3000, it specifies @resource. Since I don't have devise controllers, I don't know exactly what @resource refers to . . .

I realize this isn't much information, but I'm not sure what else to include. Does anyone have any ideas for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Look in `log/development.log` file when you see the `this webpage is not available` message; there is likely to be a more specific error message & error stack there.

Comment: I can't seem to open my log/development.log file! The production and test logs open, but not the development one. I'm just having a great day . . . Thanks for the tip, though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the link is directing you to rails server in development at localhost:3000. Change (or add) it in config/environments/development.rb .

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ..... }   # eg. { host: 'localhost:3000' }
```

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten to do this, but it doesn't seem to help with this specific problem. The confirmation link still calls for localhost:3000. Do you know how I can access the definition of the variable @resource in devise? That seems to be the weak link!

Comment: @EllenW are you doing this on a production server or local dev server ? You would need to accordingly manage both the hosts in production.rb and development.rb.  Also are you using the default link for confirmation ?

Comment: Hi, I'm currently working on my "local" server, nitrous.io. I have the same problem in production as well.

Comment: Devise is writing the email for me, and I don't know how to get in and change the link--or rather, I can get into the email, but what it calls for is "@resource," rather than a hard-coded url, and since I can't access the devise controllers, I don't know exactly what "@resource" refers to. So I guess the answer to your question is, yes, I'm using the default link.

Answer (score 0):

Your development.rb file needs to point to your hosted environment. So:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://something-yada.use1.nitrousbox.com }
```

That should take care of your issue. Remember localhost points to your local machine whereas Nitrous is a hosted environment.